# Планировщик заданий, некорректно запускается программа

Tags: windows, windows-10, администрирование, windows-server, планировщик-задач

У меня есть программа, которая запускает бота в телеграмме. То есть, когда запущена программа, то работает и бот. Но в программе есть такой "косяк" (разработчики предупредили), что она может сама завершаться.
Всё время за ней следить и перезапускать её нереально. Поэтому было принято решение воспользоваться планировщиком задач. Когда программа завешает работу, она по заданию запускается вновь.
Задание отрабатывает. Но почему-то, когда программа запускается именно через планировщик заданий, то бот не работает. Если же вручную открыть, закрыть и снова открыть программу, то всё нормально.
Я вот думаю, может я чего неправильно прописал в триггере? Или ещё где-то ошибся. Уже кучу вариантов перепробовал.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть причина такого поведения программы при запуске через планировщик. И как её устранить.
Вот сам триггер:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">
*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and Task = 13313 and (band(Keywords,9007199254740992)) and (EventID=4689)]]
and
*[EventData[(Data='C:\Users\svcBackupAccount\AppData\Local\Programs\Бот\source.exe')]]
</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Возможно, что-то не так с путём, где располагается exe-файл. Но он действительно расположен в указанном каталоге.

Comment: Есть предположение, что необходимо абсолютный путь к каталогу программы сложить с относительным путём к файлу, чтобы получить абсолютный путь к искомому файлу. Тогда процесс сможет нормально отработать. 
Но я так запутался уже, что даже не знаю, как в итоге будет выглядеть путь...

Comment: *когда программа запускается именно через планировщик заданий, то бот не работает.* Проверьте, от имени какой учётной записи запускается программа, и с каким текущим каталогом. Попробуйте запуск не напрямую, а через `CMD /c`, или даже через `START /w` .